# JIRA/JQL exclude by specific comment?

Tags: filter, jira, jql, freetext

I can easily find issues with a specific comment which might end up as 6 out of 30 items.

But I want to **exclude** each item containing a specific text string to get the remaining items.

(I'm NOT admin in our system, just a regular user)

Can do:

`comment ~ "Fault Slip Through"` = 6 out of 30

No use:

`comment !~ "Fault Slip Through"` = 30 out of 30

Need: filter out "lack of specific comment" = 24 out of 30

This way of filtering actual do work on "summary" since it also supports "in" and "not in". Is this due to comments are multiple sub items under each item?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such a problem, I found such a solution:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jql-queries-search-for-issues-that-do-not-contain-text-1018761257.html

in short:

Perform the following JQL search to find all the issues containing the text first.

```
text ~ 'ABC'
```

Save this search as a filter. Let's say the filter name is FILTER.
Navigate away from the filter page and go back to the issue search page. Type the following filter.

```
filter != FILTER
```

Once you filter out the issues that do contain the text, you can use the "!=" with the filter to find out all the issues that don't contain the text.